# stop processes in batch files with python

Tags: python, batch-file, automation

I am new to programming and I want to make a python tool to automate a process. I want to end a running batch file without killing it, is this even possible?
I don't want to kill it, because it scans for IP packages in running time and when stopped, creates a file with the data, and I want to work with this file.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Please read the results found by the Stack Overflow search [\[python\] terminate process](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+terminate+process). A batch file is processed by the Windows command processor `cmd.exe`. There can be executed at any time multiple instances of `cmd.exe`, some with a visible console window and others running completely in background. So there is needed the process identifier (pid) of the `cmd.exe` instance which is currently processing the batch file to terminate.

Comment: Why should Python, one of the most more powerful script interpreters, be used to stop the least powerful script interpreter `cmd.exe` processing a batch file? Whatever the batch file does, it can be done also with Python code in a Python script file. So this is clearly an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). The Python script should be coded to do what the `cmd.exe` currently does on processing the batch file making it easy to stop the processing by same Python script on a user action like pressing a key or clicking on a button.

Answer (score 0):

```
subprocess.call("taskkill /F /im process.exe")
```

Comment: The usage of option `/F` is never needed to terminate the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` processing a batch file. But the posted code does not work for the task to __terminate__ the processing of a batch file. The posted runs `%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe` (hopefully as called without its fully qualified file name) to __force__ a __kill__ of __all__ running instances of `process.exe` by the operating system which can easily result in corruption of files and registry entries. This answer is complete nonsense for the task to terminate a specific instance of `cmd.exe` processing a bat.

Answer (score 0):

In your batch file, at an appropriate point, try

```
if not exist stop.txt goto continue
del stop.txt
:wait
timeout /t 1 >nul 
if not exist start.txt goto wait
del start.txt
:continue
```

Use python to create `stop.txt`. Wait until `stop.txt` is deleted and read your log file. Then create `start.txt` to restart.

I'm assuming that your log file is actually closed - that us your logging is

```
echo .... >>logfile
```

not

```
(
 command-sequence
)>logfile
```

where the logfile is not closed until the command-sequence block is terminated.